# Android 4.4.2 Async Task's onProgresUpdate method is not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I update my activity's data with a Async task. it works on all the devices till date, but in Android 4.2.2 KitKat AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate method is not working.

Below is reference code of AsyncTask

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    boolean flag = true;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while(flag)
        {
            // do background Task

            //publishProgress
            publishProgress("");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //Update UI
    }
}
```

And this code how i Start AsyncTask

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    else
        asyncTask.execute(params);
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? what breaks? what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing the params to the task when the version is Honeycomb or above.  Try this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
else
    asyncTask.execute(params);
```

See this link for more detail: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29

Answer (score -1):

doInBackground() is never called.